# How to solve the problem: "'Tensor' object does not support item assignment"

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I tried to sum up element-wise two tensors but, failed.
My code is as below. 
I want to assign elements of 'a' as [x[0]*y[0]-x[1]*y[1], x[0]*y[1]+x[1]*y[0], x[2]*y[2]-x[3]*y[3], x[2]*y[3]+x[3]*y[2]].
Since I'm a beginner in Keras and tensorflow, I don't wanna use 'session' in tensorflow. How can I assign the above value merely using keras backend?

```
from keras import backend as K
def rayleigh_fading(x):
    global noise_std, n_channel
    y = K.random_normal((2*n_channel,), mean=0, stddev=1.0)*(1/np.sqrt(2))
    a = K.placeholder(shape=(4,))
    a[0] = x[0]*y[0]-x[1]*y[1]
    a[1] = x[0]*y[1]+x[1]*y[0] 
    a[2] = x[2]*y[2]-x[3]*y[3]
    a[3] = x[2]*y[3]+x[3]*y[2]
    z = a + K.random_normal((2*n_channel,), mean=0, sttdev=noise_std)
return z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

keras = tf.keras

from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

noise_std = 1
n_channel = 2

def rayleigh_fading(x):
    global noise_std, n_channel
    y = K.random_normal((K.shape(x)[0], 2*n_channel,), mean=0, stddev=1.0)*(1/np.sqrt(2))
    a0 = x[:, 0]*y[:, 0]-x[:, 1]*y[:, 1]
    a1 = x[:, 0]*y[:, 1]+x[:, 1]*y[:, 0] 
    a2 = x[:, 2]*y[:, 2]-x[:, 3]*y[:, 3]
    a3 = x[:, 2]*y[:, 3]+x[:, 3]*y[:, 2]
    a_tensors = [K.expand_dims(t) for t in [a0, a1, a2, a3]]
    a = K.concatenate(a_tensors, axis=1)
    z = a + K.random_normal((2*n_channel,), mean=0, stddev=noise_std)
    return z

def make_model():
  inp = keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,))
  rf = keras.layers.Lambda(rayleigh_fading)(inp)
  out = keras.layers.Dense(1)(rf)
  model = keras.models.Model(inp, out)
  model.compile('adam', 'mse')
  return model

model = make_model()
model.summary()
```

I assume that `y` should sample from a random variable on a per batch basis; `z` should most likely have a shape (batch_size, 2*n_channel) also... where batch_size is `K.shape(x)[0]`.

The main issue with your attempt is that a placeholder is not a variable that can be modified. It is a placeholder for input data to the model. Also you should take into account that at the tensor level `x` has a batch dimension. So to access the first column of `x` across all batches you need to use `x[:, 0]`.

I avoided creating a variable for `a` by just concatenating the vectors in your equation.

Comment: Thanks, I will try concatenating each tensor as you said! Also, I should have taken batch size into account.